# Image looks blur after down sampling

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I am developing a small project which has zoom functionality but when i zoom down image looses it's quality to remain it's original quality I have used following code for image down sampling but when i scale down image it looks blur(looks dull) and for down scaling required lots of time i need fast down scale  please help me correct my code. Thanks in advance..

```
Bitmap downscaleBitmap_new(Bitmap src,int targetWidth, int targetHeight, int off)
 {
     float r = (src.getWidth()-off)/(float)targetWidth;
     float s = (src.getHeight()-off)/(float)targetHeight;
     Bitmap target = Bitmap.createBitmap(Math.round(src.getWidth()/r), Math.round(src.getHeight()/s), Config.ARGB_8888);
     r = src.getWidth()/(float)target.getWidth();
     s = src.getHeight()/(float)target.getHeight();
     int argb;
     int red;
     int green;
     int blue;
     int alpha;
     float wx;
     float wy;
     float n;
     for(int i=0;i<target.getWidth();++i){
         for(int j=0;j<target.getHeight();++j){
             red = 0;
             green = 0;
             blue = 0;
             alpha = 0;
             n=0;
             for(int k =(int)(i*r);k<Math.round((i+1)*r);++k){
                 if(k<i*r){
                     wx = k-i*r+1;
                 }else{
                     if(k+1>(i+1)*r)
                         wx = (i+1)*r-k;
                     else
                         wx = 1;
                 }
                 for(int l=(int)(j*s);l<Math.round((j+1)*s);++l){
                     if(l<j*s){
                         wy = l-j*s+1;
                     }else{
                         if(l+1>(j+1)*s)
                             wy = (j+1)*s-l;
                         else
                             wy = 1;
                     }
                     n+=wy*wx;
                     argb=src.getPixel(k, l);
                     red += wx*wy*Color.red(argb);
                     green += wx*wy*Color.green(argb);
                     blue += wx*wy*Color.blue(argb);
                     alpha += wx*wy*Color.alpha(argb);

                 }
             }
             target.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb((int)(alpha/n), (int)(red/n), (int)(green/n), (int)(blue/n)));
         }
     }
     return target;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think down scaling the image will not change its quality? You will get poor quality due to interpolation. There is no way to retain the quality of the image. You may use Cubic or bilinear Interpolation instead of linear for better output.

`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, new_width, new_height, true);`

This will use bilinear filter and you will get good results. If you want better performance, you might want to check out renderscript and implement a better algorithm. You could also use 3rd party libraries like OpenCV or other image processing libraries, but it would be pretty heavy on the app.

Comment: Thanks for answering.. Actually i used createScaledBitmap  when i zoom down image it get very worst quality .. i need to apply image filter when zoom down ends.Please share some links of 3rd party libraries,OpenCV or renderscript

Comment: Just a thought, when you zoom out, you could reduce the size of the canvas/imageview, and render a bitmap. I think android would take care of the quality.